# Unpacking list column into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I am trying to unpack (stack) a `string` column like `dist` and `time` values into a new `df` look like in the result `df`

```
df
id     hour     dow                     dist                  time
 1   (0,10)   (0,2) [(0,1), (5,7), (8,1000)]     [1.23, 5.20, 3.2]
 2. (11,15)   (3,4)               [(8,1000)]                [18.3]
 3.  (0,10)   (5,5)           [(0,1), (2,4)]            [4.5, 6.2]
```

to expected result:

```
id     hour   dow      dist    time
 1   (0,10)  (0,2)    (0,1)    1.23
 1   (0,10)  (0,2)    (5,7)    5.20
 1   (0,10)  (0,2) (8,1000)     3.2
 2  (11,15)  (3,4) (8,1000)    18.3
 3   (0,10)  (5,5)    (0,1)     4.5
 3   (0,10)  (5,5)    (0,1)     6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `explode`

```
def yourexplode(df, col):

      df1 = pd.concat([ df[x].explode() for x in col], axis=1)
      return df1.join(df.drop(col, 1), how='left')

newdf = yourexplode(df,['dist','time'])
```